# magento 1.9 remove order specific in anchor tag url

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I want to specific delete order  in frontend

in

> My Account-> Myorders

[image]

Comment: You can delete it from Database.

Comment: no i want to frontend by customer

Comment: Than you need to write custom controller action and delete code.

Comment: You want to give delete order option to every customer ?

Comment: Yes every customer to given this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add code in **config.xml** file

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
      <extension>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Namespace_Extension</module>
            <frontName>catalogue</frontName>
          </args>
      </extension>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
```

after `order_id` pass in controller url

```
$delete = $this->getUrl('extension/index/index', array('order_id' => $_order->getIncrementId()));
```

after create controller and add below code

```
public function indexAction()
    {
                try {           
                    $order_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
                    $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id); 
                    Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
                    Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId())->delete();
                    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Catalogue was successfully deleted'));
                    Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
                    $this->_redirectReferer();
                }
                catch (Exception $e) 
                {
                    Mage::log("Order #" . $order_id . " could not be remvoved: " . $e->getMessage(), null, "order-delete.log");
                }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you hint how to complete this task say Levosoft is vendor & Customerdeleteorder is your custom module:
Add link in dashboard with following route:

```
/customerdeleteorder/order_id/21/customer_id/8
```

create basic file for module :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Levosoft_Customerdeleteorder>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Levosoft_Customerdeleteorder>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create front route for delete order in M1:
Levosoft_Customerdeleteorder/app/code/local/Levosoft/Customerdeleteorder/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>

    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <levosoft_customerdeleteorder>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Levosoft_Customerdeleteorder</module>
                    <frontName>customerdeleteorder</frontName>
                </args>
            </levosoft_customerdeleteorder>
        </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Then you will create controller file in the following location to handle this request.
Levosoft_Customerdeleteorder/app/code/local/Levosoft/Customerdeleteorder/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Levosoft_Customerdeleteorder_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function indexAction(){
        $order_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id'); // create link in customer dashboard and pass this order id in this link
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
// here you can write your delete logic you can get delete order code easily
if (!$order->getId()) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('This order no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            return false;
        }
          $customer_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_id'); // also attach current customer id
        // very important Now get customer session and match customer id with session id
if(same customer session exists){
// delete order
$order->delete();
 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Order was successfully deleted'));
}
else{ // non loged-in customer request to secure outside delete order via link
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Invalid request from non loged in customer'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            return false;
}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay let me check

Comment: but how can i will use? `(same customer session exists)`

Comment: $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
echo $customer->getId();
echo $customer->getName();

Comment: yes but your order delete code is not working

Comment: its not my code its magento code & it will work no issue in it to work with. You have to check order loaded or not because in above code i was using wrong $id instead of $order_id